# FullCalendar Control MVC jQuery - Multiple Calendars are being created

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I am looking to implement the [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) control provided by Adam Shaw and have been able to set my defaults and load it with events using JSONResult in my MVC control.

I have a DropDownList that I wired to JavaScript `.change`. When the user selects an item from the drop down I want to reload the calendar events based on the drop down selection.

The issue I am having is that a calendar is being created every time the selected dropdown item changes; so if the drop down selection changes 3 times I end up with 3 calendars.

This happens because `$('#calendar').fullCalendar` is creating another calendar, as it is designed to do. But how do I get it to use the same calendar to reload events based on the selected item in the drop down?

My JsonResult in my MVC Controller

```
public JsonResult CALStationDayLoad(int AppID)
        {

            var events = SL_db.SLGetStationLogFuture(null,AppID);
            var eventList = from e in events
                            select new
                            {
                                id = e.ID,
                                title = e.ShortDesc,
                                start = e.StartTime.ToString("s"),
                                end = e.EndTime.ToString("s"),
                                allDay = false
                            };

          return Json(eventList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

---

Here is the jQuery...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#AppID").change(function () {
            var e = document.getElementById("AppID");
            var selectedApp = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
           GetEvents(selectedApp);
         });
    });

    function GetEvents(AppID) {
        //console.log(AppID);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: false,
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: '',
                right: ''
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            editable: false,
            events: {
                url: '/AppPreventativeMaintenance/CALStationDayLoad/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    AppID: AppID
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                },
                //color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
                //textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
            }

        });
    };

</script>
```

Comment: try `$('#calendar').html('').fullCalendar(...);` that will clear the element to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what you want to do is move your

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
});
```

code out of the `onchange` and put it into your `ready` function. Then in your `onchange` you want to do something like this...

```
var eventSource = {
    url: '/AppPreventativeMaintenance/CALStationDayLoad/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        AppID: AppID
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    }
}

function GetEvents(AppID) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventSource);
    eventSource.data.AppID = AppID;
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventSource);
}
```

Hope this helps!